# How to initialize a firebase real time database observer in swift for Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

I've tried looking online but there's only tutorials for listeners on Firestore and I can't find any working syntax for the realtime DB.
This is code I've used so far from a video posted in 2016:
'''

```
let database = Database.database().reference()
lazy var rmRef = database.child(inPersonRm.roomCode)
rmRef.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        
})
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the correct implementation to check for changed values is to put this code in the viewDidLoad()

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child(inPersonRm.roomCode).child("roomPlayers").observe(.childChanged, with: { firDataSnapshot in
        print("bet")
    })
```

and set your ref to the child you're observing